# How to use complementary slackness to find y*?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

My Primal LP is

```
Min -5x1   - x3
      x1+ x2+ x3+ x4        =1
     2x1+ x2        + x5    =2
      x1+2x2+3x3        + x6=3
      x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 >=0
```

My dual LP is

```
Max y1+2y2+3y3
    y1+2y2+ y3<=-5
    y1+ y2+2y3<=0
    y1    +3y3<=-1
     y1,y2,y3<=0
```

x*=(1,0,0,0,0,2)

How do I find y* and z*?

Comment: Your primal LP is unbounded, A better value for the objective function is $−100$. And $x=(20,0,0,−19−38,−17)$. Or is $\color{red}{x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0}$ ?

Comment: My bad $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are $\geq0$

Comment: Are $x_4,x_5,x_6\geq 0$ as well ?

Comment: yes they are. I am getting that the dual LP is infeasible, and if that is the case there is no y* right?

Comment: No you have infinite many solution for the dual problem. The primal problem is not unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have primal problem

> Min $-5x_1   - x_3$
>
> $x_1+ x_2+ x_3+        \leq 1$
>
> $2x_1+ x_2     \ \ \quad \quad   \leq 2$
>
> $ x_1+2x_2+3x_3      \leq 3$
>
> $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0$

The other variables are can be interpreted as slack variables: $s_1, s_2$ and $s_3$. I would even say that they are slack variables. The optimal solution is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3)=(1,0,0,0,0,2)$

Then the dual problem is

> $\text{Max} \ \ y_1+2y_2+3y_3$
>
> $y_1+2y_2+y_3 \leq -5$
>
> $y_1+y_2+2y_3\leq 0$
>
> $y_1+3y_3\leq -1$
>
> $y_1,y_2,y_3\leq 0$

Using the complementary slackness theorem:

---

$x_j\cdot z_j=0 \ \forall \ \ j=1,2, \ldots , n$

$y_i\cdot s_i=0 \ \forall \ \ i=1,2, \ldots , m$

$s_i \text{ are the slack variables of the primal problem.}$

$z_j \text{ are the slack variabales of the dual problem.}$

---

We know that $x_1=1$. Thus $z_1=0$. And we get the equation

$y_1+2y_2+ y_3=-5$

And $y_3\cdot s_3=0\Rightarrow y_3=0 $

The equation above becomes $y_1+2y_2=-5$ Thus the solution is $y_1=-5-2y_2$.

Therefore you have infinitely many solutions like

$y_1^*=(-3,-1,0), y_2^*=(-1,-2,0), y_3^*=(-2, -1.5,0)$

Comment: Why did you write $y_3 \ s_3 = 0$? I don't see why that statement is true. Could you, please, elaborate? Ty.

Comment: @MasonBeau This is the application of the complementary slackness theorem.

Comment: You're right, @callculus42. I guess my question should have been: Why is the implication $y_3 = 0$ and not $s_3 = 0$? Maybe this is trivial, but I'm new to the topic and couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: @MasonBeau The optimal solution of the primal is $(x_1^*,x_2^*, x_3^*, s_1,s_2,s_3)=(1,0,0,0,0,2)$. This can be read from the question.  That means that $s_3=2\neq 0$

Comment: This is very right. I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @MasonBeau It pleases me that it is all clear now.